# Когда и зачем приходится хранить json в БД?

Tags: база-данных, json, sqlite

Я привык создавать БД с таблицами на основе тех сущностей которые приходят вместе с json, писать конвертеры из SQL представления в объектное и в обратном направлении, или использовать ORM. Но вот сейчас смотрю в проекте человек просто пишет json в БД и через GSON при обращении к БД обратно конвертирует в объекты. Сущностей всего должно быть 7 не так много, но я не понимаю зачем было записывать в одну таблицу просто json. Я уже наслышан про такой вот хранения данных в БД, но не до конца понимаю зачем так делать. Скажите пожалуйста когда это имеет смысл?!

Comment: Если это рабочие данные, по которым требуются выборки, то описанный вами путь несколько ущербный и я тоже не понимаю, зачем так делать и зачем тогда вообще БД, проще и "дешевле" в файл писать

Comment: Очень индивидуально, к примеру если есть контент провайдер, можно получать в чистом виде json, аналогично   сетевым запросам, даже не нарушая парадигму клиент сервер со стороны клиента, что возможно было бы удобно. Ну и вопрос по безопасности данных, тоже нужно учесть

Answer (score 8):

Я считаю, что `JSON`'ом можно хранить данные в БД в том случае, если из них не нужно делать выборку. То есть, когда в любом случае из БД загружаются сразу все данные.
Но, как по мне, в таком случае лучше обойтись и вовсе без БД, т. к. смысл ее в том, чтобы позволять сделать именно выборку. Я бы такие данные хранил просто в файле.

Comment: "хранил просто в файле": могут быть проблемы с неконсистентностью, с транзакциями, с резервным копированием.
В остальном - согласен

Answer (score 5):

Основную информацию храню по столбцам как положено, если необходимо хранить некие параметры, например параметры отображения информации которые не участвуют в поиске или обработки сохраняю как Json.

Answer (score 4):

Хранить json в БД имеет смысл, если у вас есть большое количество переменных параметров, по которым не надо делать выборку.

Допустим у вам надо сделать планировщик задач. Задач много, для описания каждой используются множество переменных. Например запустить произвольный shell скрипт с индивидуальными параметрами.

```
task_id  task_type task_parameters
1        shell     {"script":"mkdir","params":["/home/user","dir_name","770"]}
2        push      {"vendor":"android","payload":"bla-bla-bla"}
```